# How to get the current locale's alphabet?

Tags: android, unicode, localization, locale

### Background

Today I've noticed that on [Google's Contacts app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.contacts), if you have both English and Hebrew contacts, and you switch to English locale as the main one, the first contacts are in English:

[image]

But, if you switch to Hebrew locale as the main one, the first contacts are in Hebrew:

[image]

### The problem

I don't see which functions are used to do that. I tried to search over the Internet about this behavior and how it's done, but couldn't find it.

Comparing the values of characters will always return the same result, so the order here should be more dynamic.

### What I've found

I thought this will help me:

```
val unicodeLocaleKeys = Locale.getDefault().unicodeLocaleKeys
```

But it always returns an empty set.

I also searched for such a function in classes such as Character, Unicode*, and String. I don't think it exists there.

### The question

How does Google Contacts app get to sort the contacts by the current locales?

Is it possible perhaps to get the whole set of characters used by a specific locale?

Maybe it's possible to compare characters, while giving order of priorities of locales (users can choose multiple locales) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking on the wrong thing.

Contact app seems not to have an alphabet built in (per locale), but just a collation (local sort) and display the first character. Possibly it will find "symbols" (Unicode categories) and put all symbols in the same *bin*.

Eventually you can get, from Unicode, the script name (and the direction). You may get the alphabet in few places (e.g. Wikipedia). It will fail for Chinese, and other rich *alphabets*. The problem: the "alphabet" is language specific. On some European countries you may have (some) accented characters, or character groups interpreted as a single character (also on phone books).

So, if you want to keep thing simple:

- use collation and just first character
- the same, but remove accent, and try to find if the letter has same priority in alphabetic order: in this case: ignore accent, else: keep it, see e.g.[Å - place in alphabet](/en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85#Place_in_alphabet). Maybe do the same with two letters, e.g. [ll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ll) in the past.
- find a library with handle such complex cases (and that it will updated regularly). This will help probably for Chinese and other languages with huge amount of characters.

---

EDIT: in short, instead of normal sorting of strings using `str1.compareTo(str2)`, you should use :

```
Collator.getInstance().compare(str1,str2)
```

Comment: Why do you think it works in a different way? What is the clue that caused you to think this way? And what do you mean by "collation"? All I can say is that from the POV of the user, this is what I see: Changing the locale will change the order of the contacts. For English it's from a-z (and upper case) and for Hebrew it's from א-ת (and the special characters) . Do you say that it's by chance? that if I use another language I won't see this behavior? I don't understand :(

Comment: "Collation" is one part of locale definition: alphabetic sorting (the other parts: numerical representation, currency representation, character set, date representation, and other 2 parts IIRC). Changing locale, you get a different sort. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html (which BTW provide primary, which is what you look [A,a,à weight the same on primary weight], so my second point will be much easier). -- see also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/CollationElementIterator.html

Comment: I've tested. Seems this you are correct and the next code produces different result when using a English locale vs when using Hebrew locale: `Collator.getInstance().compare("א", "A")` . So maybe it's what's used on this app. I asked about "collation" because I didn't know its meaning, and translating to my language (Hebrew), it's just like "gathering", which doesn't say much. Anyway, but is it possible to get all characters of a locale, though?

Comment: The problem is that in every language you have many characters, not just the "alphabet", and one should possibly sort foreign names. Your question is real, but I never thought about it, and I do not remember to have seen such problem earlier.

Comment: There is some information in https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-collation.html#Collation_Indexes so there should be somewhere a function to get what you are looking for. [I think both Android and Java do not yet use Unicode Locale for locale definitions]

Comment: Yes I know there are multiple characters. I meant to include them too. In Hebrew for example instead of vowels we have special signs around the letters (called "Nikud" which means "making dots", because they are usually dots). I will now accept your answer because that's the original source of my question, but I still would like to know if it's possible to get all the characters set of a given locale. Might be useful some day. If you find it, I will also give you +1. As for your answer, I will now edit it to include the code for comparison.